# MathJax <msup> font modificaion

Tags: mathjax

I am trying to implement some math expressions/equations in html5 using mathjax. When using an  <msup> tag I get inconsistent behavior in font style depending on what the exponent/power is. Is there an attribute I can implement on the  <msup> tag or the  <mi> /  <mn> tag that will keep the power the same font as its base? Or another option to keep the font styles consistent?

`<math><mrow><msup><mi></mi><mi>x</mi></msup></mrow></math>`

- base and power are the same font

`<math><mrow><msup><mi></mi><mi>-x</mi></msup></mrow></math>`

- adding a negative power causes mathjax to render the power a different font

I was unsuccessful implementing mathjax in this question so here is a link to a jsfiddle that illustrates my issue

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ez5kqv7x/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear from the OP but it probably refers to the fact that `<mi>x</mi>` will be typeset italic whereas `<mi>-x</mi>` will be rendered normal/upright.

This is the expected result as the [MathML Spec](https://www.w3.org/Math/draft-spec/mathml.html#chapter3_presm.mi) says for `<mi>`:

> The default is "normal" (non-slanted) unless the content is a single character, in which case it would be "italic".

For identifiers, one would probably mark this up as `<mo form="prefix">-</mo><mi>x</mi>` in which case the `x` would end up italic again; but perhaps the `x` is really a number in which case `<mn>x</mn>` and `<mn>-x</mn>` would both be typset normal/upright.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but <mo form="prefix">-</mo><mi>x</mi> causes mathjax to render the "-" as the superscript and "x" as the subscript (assuming I understood your post correctly) [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uajkmn5t/) . It appears msup can only accept two or three variables, the first being the base and the second being the power & the second variable (as you have highlighted in the mathml documentation, only allows for one character if you want italics font, and the third being a subscript.This still leaves the issue unresolved. Any other thoughts on ways around this limitation?

Comment: Found the solution. Peter's post above lead me right to it. In the Mathml documentation you can add an attribute mathvariant='italics' to override the behaviour of the msup stylisation against an mi tag. Final solution that appears to work would be <mrow><msup><mi>x</mi><mi mathvariant='italic'>-x</mi></msup></mrow>

Comment: Ah, sorry about that; by the time I had looked up the correct links I must have had forgotten that you were asking about msup's (which expects exactly two children and thus requires mrows as you figured out).